# Why should the speed of light necessarily be the same for all observers in train thought experiment?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

I am learning about train thought experiment that explains  relativity of simultaneity , but this picture confuses my mind. It seems to me even if the  speed of light is not the same for all observers, that it behaves like low speeds  if lights strike when train is nearer to point B than it is to point A, from point B to the bus  the speed of light is 4/5c +c, we will also get the same conclusion- the observer in the train will see the light B before he sees light A. But if  the lights strike when train is nearer to point A than it is to point B, then the speed of light should be the same for all observers in order to get the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special relativity is based on the assumption that the laws of physics are the same in any inertial reference frame. (On a commercial airliner, you can eat, sleep, read, or go the the rest room if the plane is at rest or moving at 600 mph.) Maxwell's equations for the interaction of electric and magnetic fields can be used to predict the speed of light. Since the equations are valid for any inertial frame, then the speed of light must be the same in any inertial frame.

Comment: Great answer!I like this answer because it says that SR is a consequence of experemints of classical electrodynamics +1.